# Create In-Memory-Image for testing with Werkzeug

Tags: python, post, python-imaging-library, werkzeug

I'm currently trying to generate an in-memory image-file, that i want to `upload` to a server. I'm writing a testcase for a file-upload-method written with `Werkzeug`. Werkzeug has support for files, i can access the file via `request.files` and werkzeug hast testing-utilities which let me specify a file-like object to upload:

```
builder = EnvironBuilder(path="/someurl", method='POST',
                         data={'foo': 'this is some text',
                               'file': (StringIO('my file contents'), 'test.txt'),
                               'img': (Helper.create_image_file(), "img.png"),
                         })
```

Code to store file (shortend):

```
path = request.files['img'].filename 
request.files['img'].save(path)
```

Now what i cant figure out is what i have to pass as the key `file` to actually get an image to the processing method. My current approach is as follows

```
@classmethod
def create_image_file(cls, height=200, width=200):
    """ Create an in-memory image-file with the given height and width """
    from PIL import Image       
    size = (height, width)
    color = (255,255,0,0)
    img = Image.new("RGBA", size, color)        
    return StringIO(img.tostring())
```

Which only results in not-readable file on disk. So, how do i have to pass an in-memory-image to werkzeug, so the data is actually correct and stored correctly?

Comment: Btw.: you can store a file with `request.files['img'].save(dest)`.

Comment: Thanks, edited it in. Any hints on the other problem? :)